# How can I make a Dynamic Dropdown in WordPress using wp job board pro plugin?

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, dropdown

Certainly! I'm using the `wp job board pro` plugin on my WordPress site and need assistance creating a form exclusively within this plugin. Despite searching through various Google articles and ChatGPT resources, I couldn't find a reliable guide. While I understand the concept of conditional fields, the plugin lacks an option to define conditions. Specifically, I want to implement a dropdown functionality where selecting a country in the first dropdown dynamically updates the second dropdown with corresponding states. For instance, if I choose India in the first dropdown, the second dropdown should display states like West Bengal. Can you guide me on achieving this?

[given options are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU1VF.png)

I am expecting to get dynamic dropdown using `wp job board pro` plugin in WordPress

Comment: This question needs some code. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

A: Most dynamic dropdown plugins are designed to be compatible with a wide range of themes, but it's advisable to check the plugin documentation for specific compatibility information, [look for more](https://wordpress.org/plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

Understand WP Job Board Pro Custom Fields:
WP Job Board Pro allows you to create custom fields for your job listings. You'll utilize this feature to create the dynamic dropdown.

Create a Custom Field:
Go to your WordPress admin dashboard and navigate to "WP Job Board" > "Settings" > "Custom Fields". Create a new custom field of type "Dropdown".

Implement a Dynamic Dropdown:
To make the dropdown dynamic, you'll need to populate its options dynamically based on some criteria. For example, let's say you want to populate the dropdown with a list of countries.

Utilize a Callback Function:
You can use a callback function to dynamically generate the options for the dropdown. Here's an example of how you might do this:

```
function populate_country_dropdown_options(){
        
    $countries = array(
        array(
            'value' => 'CAN',
            'description' => 'Canada'
        ),
        array(
            'value' => 'PK',
            'description' => 'Pakistan'
        ),
        array(
            'value' => 'US',
            'description' => 'United States'
        ),
    );
    
       return $countries;
}
```